# Parse error in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, syntax-error

```
    $labels = (
        'steam' => 'Steam',
        'bore_water' => 'Bore Water',
        'boiler1oil' => 'Boiler 1 Oil',
    );
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected `T_DOUBLE_ARROW` on line 32: `'steam' => 'Steam',`

Can anyone spot the issue with this?

Comment: You are missing the `array` keyword.

Comment: @Pekka: You typed in the wrong textarea.

Comment: ircmaxell. At least he said *where* your code is wrong.

Comment: @Albert thank you. I won't be running out of a lack of time, and because I'm leaving the industry this spring so I won't be that active on SO any more. (related [chat discussion](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/458776#458776))

Comment: @Pekka: Yeah I heard. At least get to 100k first though, you're so close! :)

Comment: @BoltClock heh! :) I probably won't make it because I'm spending so much on bounties! I need to get a rep count without bounties....

Comment: This is pointless. I deleted my post. At least I get the batge for deleting 3+ post :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$labels = array(
    'steam' => 'Steam',
    'bore_water' => 'Bore Water',
    'boiler1oil' => 'Boiler 1 Oil',
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `array`:

```
$labels = array(
    'steam' => 'Steam',
    'bore_water' => 'Bore Water',
    'boiler1oil' => 'Boiler 1 Oil',
);
```